# Ubuntu install - fatal error grub-install /dev/sda

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I am new to Ubuntu. I tried to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, but the installation failed.

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

returned `fatal error`.

When I try to log back into Windows, I have `grub-rescue` message.
I can only access Ubuntu through the trial version.
My PC is 7 years old and I can only boot through the CD (and not through a flash drive). It looks like the trial version does not allow me to download a cd-writer software!

I am a bit a lost.. any idea?

Comment: How was Windows installed? UEFI or Legacy mode?